# How to disconnect completely on BLE using iOS Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral, ios-bluetooth

When using CBCentralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral) , disconnection is only for the application level. So can't connect again to the same device without turn off and on bluetooth.

I know that CBCentralManager?.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: ) function is there, but I need to connect to the exact same device( based on MAC address [ This I'm getting from advertising data ] ) not to any device with the specific service.

Is there any way to disconnect completely?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to disconnect completely.

You can just call [`connect(_:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518766-connectperipheral) within [`centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518791-centralmanager). The device will be reconnected once it is visible again.